# API access from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

1. I want to create a ADF pipeline which needs to access an API and using some filter parameter it will get data from there and write the output in JSON format in DataLake. How can I do that??
2. After the JSON available in Lake it needs to be converted to CSV file. How to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pipeline with copy activity from HTTP connector to Datalake connector. Use HTTP as the copy source to access the API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http), specify the format in dataset as JSON. Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#json-format on how to define the schema. Use Datalake connector as the copy sink, specify the format as Text format, and do some modification like row delimiter and column delimiter according to your need.

Comment: -  Thanks for your reply. I am quite new in this but as far as I came to know, that request doesn't allow more than 100 rows/objects in one JSON file... in that case how to capture it in loop? any example code would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

the below work follow may meet your requirement:

1. Involve a [Copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) in ADFv2, where the source dataset is [HTTP data store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http) and the destination is the [Azure Data lake store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-store), HTTP source data store allows you to fetch data by calling API and Copy activity will copy data into your destination data lake.
2. Chain an [U-SQL activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-data-lake-analytics) after Copy activity, once the Copy activity succeeds, it'll run the U-SQL script to convert json file to CSV file.